# Remove Side Portion from DefaultTabController in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, flutter-layout

I am using DefaultTabController widget in Flutter and the output is as below :

[image]

I want to remove left and right white background portion as you can see it in above image.
How can I remove that portion or can change the color to dark ?

So far I am trying it as below :

```
return ThemeData(
  tabBarTheme: const TabBarTheme(

  ),
  );
```

Now, here I am not able to find property that changes the white color to dark color. Please guide. Thanks.

**Code :**

```
return DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleSpacing: 24.w,
        centerTitle: false,
        title: Text(
          Localization.of(context).labelFacilities,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: getBool(isDarkMode) ? whiteColor : textColorBlack,
              fontSize: 20.sp),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.w),
            child: Image.asset(icSearch,
                width: 18.w,
                height: 18.h,
                color: getBool(isDarkMode) ? whiteColor : textColorBlack),
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        elevation: 0,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: _tabBar.preferredSize,
          child: Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.w), //<-- SEE HERE
            child: Container(
              child: _tabBar,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: lightYellowColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.w)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.w),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.h, right: 24.w, left: 24.w),
        child: TabBarView(
          children: [
            AttractionsScreen(),
            EventsScreen(),
            UtilitiesScreen(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Tabbar widget is created as below :

```
 TabBar get _tabBar => TabBar(
      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      indicatorWeight: 1,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        fontSize: 14.h,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      ),
      //For Selected tab
      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        fontSize: 14.h,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      ),
      labelColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedLabelColor: textColorBlack,
      indicator: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.w), color: yellowColor),
      tabs: [
        Tab(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(Localization.of(context).labelAttractions),
          ),
        ),
        Tab(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(Localization.of(context).labelEvents),
          ),
        ),
        Tab(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(Localization.of(context).labelUtilities),
          ),
        ),
      ]);
```

Comment: Can you include your TabBar  snippet

Comment: code added pls check

Answer (score 3):

You can find some `padding` properties on `TabBar` and set it zero.

```dart
TabBar(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  tabs: [....],
),
```

Comment: not working with this...

Comment: Can you include a sample widget that will reproduce the same error.

Comment: code added pls check

Comment: Can you try removing `margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.w)`, also you might want padding instead of margin

Comment: Its margin, not padding..

Comment: In that case it spreaded and occupied full screen, I have to give margin right and left to 24

Answer (score 1):

#1 You can add color in

```
Material(
color: "YOUR_COLOR",
)
```

#2 Remove that portion

Code:

```
PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: _tabBar.preferredSize,
          child: Material(
            color: lightYellowColor, // <-- Change color HERE
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.w), //<-- SEE HERE
            child: Container(
              child: _tabBar,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: lightYellowColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.w)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.w), //<--Remove that portion 
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: In that case it spreaded and occupied full screen, I have to give margin right and left to 24

Comment: You can use `#1 `change the color to dark